# Callout text not respecting space(s) between words in ArcGIS Pro Layout

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts, callout, text-element

I suspect that I may have inadvertently changed a setting somewhere in ArcGIS Pro 2.6.2 because when I use Callout (Sans Serif) as my Default Text Symbol any space(s) I use between words in the text I am trying to place are not appearing in the expected way.

To reproduce this try the following:

1. Start ArcGIS Pro and use **Start without a template** to create a new project
2. Insert a **New Layout** (I used A4,Portrait)
3. Use the **dialog launcher** of the **Graphics and Text** button group to open the Options dialog to the Text and Graphics tab

[image]

4. Click the **Reset to Defaults** button to try and clear any inadvertent settings
5. Click OK to close the Options dialog and accept those Default symbols
6. Use the **Rectangle text** button in the gallery of the Graphics and Text button group to drag out some text
7. Use the **Element pane** (which has Format Text as its title) to set the Text to be **Project Site**
8. Zoom the page so that the text element just added is easy to see, and there's room to add a few more below it.  The words Project Site have the expected space between them on the layout.

[image]

9. Use the **dialog launcher** of the **Graphics and Text** button group to open the Options dialog again, and change the Default Text Symbol to be **Callout (Sans Serif)**

[image]

10. Use the **Rectangle text** button in the gallery of the Graphics and Text button group to drag out some text below the first text element at about the same size
11. Use the Element pane (which has Format Text as its title) to set the Text to be Project Site

[image]

The expected space between the two words of Project Site is missing, and the "t" of Project even overlaps the "S" of Site.

12. Use the **Rectangle text** button in the gallery of the Graphics and Text button group to drag out a third text element below the first two at about the same size
13. Use the Element pane (which has Format Text as its title) to set the Text to be Project   Site (with three spaces between the two words)

[image]

The overlap between the two words of Project Site is now even more pronounced.

Why is the spacing between words not being respected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just retested the procedure in my question using ArcGIS Pro 3.0.0.

The callout text element produced had the expected space(s) between words in the text so it looks like what I believe to have been a bug was addressed somewhere between versions 2.6.2 and 3.0.0

Answer (score -1):

Symbo > Formatting > Set wordSpacing to 100%[image]

Comment: The pane that you have in your picture does not look like it comes from a graphic text element like the one I used in my procedure.  Instead it looks like it comes from feature class labeling.